# verbo reflexivo vs pronominal

Tags: reflexivos, verbo-pronominal

1. ¿Todo los  verbos reflexivos son verbos pronominales?
2. ¿Solo se puede identificar si los verbos son pronominales o no revisando los diccionarios?
3. ¿Todos los verbos pueden ser pronominales?
4. ¿Qué es la función de pronominal?

Comment: Sí. Todavía tengo otras dudas que necesito hacer la pregunta.

Comment: Your questions are quite broad: could you indicate some specific cases you are facing problems with? If you haven’t done so already, browse through the reflexivos and verbo-pronominal tags to see other questions about this. They may help you get examples and explanations. If you can narrow down your question afterwards, use edit to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Estas preguntas son difíciles de responder, por lo amplias, y las respuestas disponibles suelen ser complejas, así que intentaré resumir. Si te queda alguna duda particular sobre algún verbo, no dudes en preguntar, y buscaremos dar respuestas más específicas y detalladas.

**1. ¿Todos los verbos reflexivos son verbos pronominales?** No. Un verbo reflexivo "de verdad" indica una acción reflexiva, es decir, donde el subjeto y el objeto indican la misma persona o cosa. Por ejemplo: *Yo me miro en el espejo.* El que se mira y lo que mira son la misma persona (yo). En cambio, un verbo pronominal no es reflexivo, aunque pueda parecerlo: *Yo me enojo mucho.* Esto no quiere decir que yo me provoco o me causo enojo *a mí mismo*. Otro ejemplo más claro: *Yo me caigo.* El verbo *caer* es intransitivo, así que no hay manera de que pueda ser reflexivo.

**2. ¿Solo se puede identificar si los verbos son pronominales o no revisando los diccionarios?** No. Si en una oración aparece un pronombre "reflexivo" y sabes que el verbo no puede ser reflexivo (porque es intransitivo o porque no tiene sentido), entonces es pronominal. Por ejemplo, el caso de *caer*.

**3. ¿Todos los verbos pueden ser pronominales?** No. Hay muchos, muchísimos verbos que pueden volverse pronominales, como *enojar*, *caer* o *morir* (o sea, que pueden estar en la forma básica (*Él muere*) o en forma pronominal (*Él se muere*). A veces la forma pronominal quiere decir prácticamente lo mismo que la forma básica, otras no. También hay algunos verbos que sólo pueden ser pronominales, como *arrepentirse*.

**4. ¿Qué es la función de pronominal?** No hay una única función. No puede decirse que "cuando un verbo se hace pronominal, significa esto o lo otro". Hay algunas tendencias, pero el tema de los verbos pronominales es un campo de estudio demasiado amplio para resumirlo aquí. Para la cuestión del *significado* de un verbo no sirve de nada saber que es pronominal.

Comment: No sé a qué se refiere @rafael, ojalá y explique un poco más.  Yo iba a decir que en el segundo punto valdría la pena explicar *pronombre "reflexivo"*, porque quizás no se va a entender por qué pusiste comillas.  Creo que te refieres a los pronombres que se usan con los verbos reflexivos (*me, te, se, nos, se*). Pero me encanta la respuesta, porque yo sabía *usar* low pronominales pero no había entendido la teoría bien hasta leer esta respuesta.

Comment: Relacionado la pregunta número 4 -- ¿Siempre existe alguna diferencia, aunque sea muy sutil, entre la version pronominal y la versión no pronominal (cuando existen las dos formas)?  ¿ Hay algún término que signifique 'no pronominal'?

Comment: @Rafael - Gracias por explicar.  Creí que te referías al primer punto (bullet).  Bien.  Por lo que yo sé de Pablo, no creo que tomara mal que editaras el prólogo.  Si no estás cómodo con esa idea, podrías proponer un *edit* en forma de comentario.

Comment: Entiendo que puede tomarse mal la forma de expresión, pero también creo que las sutilezas podrían escapársele a una persona que no domina el idioma, como en este caso. "Tus preguntas son básicas" me resultaría grosero a mí en algunos contextos. Acabo de editar la respuesta, espero que suene un poco mejor.

Comment: @aparente001 No sé si hay un término que signifique "no pronominal". Yo vengo usando la expresión "forma básica" vs. "forma pronominal" cuando un verbo tiene las dos. En cuanto a lo primero (si siempre hay alguna diferencia), diría que sí (porque no existen los sinónimos exactos).

Comment: @pablodf76 - Disculpa, no sé a cuál pregunta dices que sí.  // Voy a imaginar que estoy en un plan súper sensible, y tratar de resolver el problemilla que destació rafael.  No dudes de hacer un rollback si no lo sientes de tu estilo.

Comment: @Rafael - ¿Qué tal ahora?

Comment: @aparente001 mucho mejor!